# Book: Female protagonist transformed into alien on alien planet

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I have been trying to figure this out for years. There is another posting that is similar, but I'm not sure if it's the same.

Female protagonist, I don't remember how she finds herself on the alien planet, but she is injured or stranded or something so the aliens transform her into one of them. From what I recall they are frog like, forest dwelling, and I vaguely recall telepathic communication?

At some point there are other humans, and she turns back into a human. I remember a really bizarre, out of place, graphic sex scene with a fellow human.

Also for some reason I keep thinking the author was maybe Swedish or Danish?

Comment: please be sure to mark the answer accepted, if you're still around these days :)

Answer (score 17):

[image: The Colour Of Distance - Amy Thompson - Book Cover]

Possibly ["**The Color of Distance**"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?250) by Amy Thomson.

> The book opens from the alien perspective with the *frog-like
> inhabitants of the rain forests* of a world called Tendu. The elders
> of one of their tribes find a bizarre new animal on the verge of death
> and perform a miraculous feat of bioengineering in order to save it.
>
> The creature's name is Juna, and *she's part of a human survey mission
> to the planet*. Her *scout ship crashed* and her crew -- clad in
> environment suits -- had been forced to try and hike back to base camp
> through the dense Tendu forest. Their *suits ruptured* during the trip,
> exposing them to an atmosphere to which their bodies were violently
> allergic. Everyone else died, and Juna expected to join them.
>
> She didn't, a fact that amazes and horrifies her when *she awakes to
> find herself transformed into something resembling the aliens*. She's
> able to breathe without life support, has a strange skin that reacts
> to her moods, and razor-sharp talons. After choking back her fear, she
> begins making contact with the intelligent aliens, hoping against hope
> that she can still get to her mothership before it leaves.

Somewhat different from your description, but the alien race communicates by altering their skin colour:

> As with many Earth frogs, they can change their skin colour. What
> started as camouflage and simple colour signals has evolved into a
> sophisticated symbolic language, presumably along the lines of
> Egyptian or Mayan hieroglyphs.

<sup>*~ Edited from [SF Site](http://www.sfsite.com/09a/col64.htm) and [SF Mistressworks](http://sfmistressworks.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/the-color-of-distance-amy-thomson/)*</sup>

There definitely is a lot of sexual content. I won't go into the details, but here's how the protagonist reacts during one such scenario:

> Her skin felt warm, as though a lover had been stroking her. She
> opened her eyes. Her skin was a brilliant, metallic gold. Was this the
> color of sexual arousal? The aliens were the same shade of gold. Juna
> fought back a wave of panic. Did this mean they wanted to have sex
> with her?

Also, the protagonist does transform back into her human form. This (weird) conversation between Juna and Bruce, her new "human" lover, should illustrate that.

> “What are you thinking?” he whispered.
>
> Juna laughed. “I was just thinking how good it is to have nipples again.”
>
> “I wouldn’t have minded you without them,” he said.
>
> “But it bothered me,” she replied.
>
> “I could have gotten used to it, Juna. I was willing to try.”

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU I even remember the cover!

Comment: Glad to help :-) Whenever you're back, do remember to mark this as "answered". Thanks and Happy Reading!

Comment: Sadly, that link at the bottom is broken now :(